# How to use IF in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a "WALMART_FLAG" value in other places. I need to replicate the calculation for the flag in this table. I believe I need to use `CASE` statement.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT s.DEAGY AS 'AGENCY', l.cmschn AS 'MASTER_CHAIN', s.DECHN AS 'CHAIN', s.DESTR AS 'STORE NUMBER', s.DEWEDT AS 'WK_ENDING',
    (CASE
        WHEN s.DEIO='O' AND s.DEAGY=10 AND s.DECHN IN (WC,WM) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END)='Y' THEN (SELECT -1 * s.DEQTY) ELSE 0
    END AS RET_UNITS

FROM LEVYDTA.SMPRTNM s
JOIN LEVYDTA.LDSCHNM l
    ON s.DEAGY=l.CMAGY and s.DECHN=l.CMCHN;
```

But I still get this error:

[image: Picture of the error]

> Incorrect syntax near '='

and

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.DEAGY AS AGENCY, l.cmschn AS MASTER_CHAIN, s.DECHN AS CHAIN,
       s.DESTR AS STORE NUMBER, s.DEWEDT AS WK_ENDING,
       CASE
           WHEN s.DEIO='O' AND DEAGY = 10 AND DECHN IN ('WC', 'WM') THEN -1 * s.DEQTY 
           ELSE 0
       END AS RET_UNITS

FROM LEVYDTA.SMPRTNM s
JOIN LEVYDTA.LDSCHNM l
   ON s.DEAGY=l.CMAGY and s.DECHN=l.CMCHN;
```

Comment: thank you. However, for some reason I get an error. Do you know what is wrong? I have attached the picture of an error.

Comment: @DIFF1, Just remove the 'AS WALMART_FLAG' keyword from your query inside the nested case.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I removed it, still get an error. Could you take  a look what is wrong, please? I have posted a screenshot.

Comment: You didn't use what I posted. I replaced the entire CASE statement, but you're stuffing unnecessary and wrong `='Y'` and `SELECT` in there.